# Image Formula Fields in HTML Email Template

Tags: apex, files, contentdocument, contentdistribution

Trying to put a Formula Field Image on an Email template so to have images unique to the Account.

So Email templates replaces `&` with `&amp;` thus the parameters in externally shared links from both Documents or ContentDistribution result in a broken image link.

Any advise here?

Comment: Replacing `&` with `&amp;` in HTML is correct, and would not be causing this problem. It may be that the file requires login in order to view. Have you tried loading the URL directly, replacing `&amp;` with `&`? Does it redirect to a login page?

Comment: I thought about that, but replacing the `&amp;` with `&` makes the image work when not logged in. It definitely seems to be the the `&amp;` breaking it

Comment: Have you tried placing the image in a static resource?  See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/206267/adding-an-image-to-the-email-template-viewable-in-gmail

Comment: Have you tried encoding the `&` sign with html encode to `%26` in the url? Can you also post a sample url that you are trying to put in the Email Template?